# Are there any ways to handle multiple elements at the same time in ksh?

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, db2, ksh

I'm trying to execute delete SQL like below in ksh.

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++))
do
  delete from TABLE1 where NAME in (${array[i]})
done
```

In this roop, I can delete row one by one. But what I want to is to delete multiple rows like 5 or 10 at the same time.

I have no idea, so I want your help.

---

Thank you, everyone! I finally could solve it by using below!

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i=i+5))
do
    echo ${array[@]:${i}:5} | sed -e s/^/\'/g | sed s/\\s/\',\'/g | sed s/$/\'/g | read array2
    delete from TABLE1 where NAME in (${array2})"
done
```

Comment: What is the content of array? Numbers? Strings? What do you mean by deleting multiple rows? e.g. array=(1,2,3,4,5) and you want to delete all rows that have name in 1,2,3,4,5? Please add more information so we can help you :)

Comment: @CarloCorradini The column `NAME` suggests that it's a string.

Comment: Convert your array to a string like `names="'name1', 'name2', 'name3'"`. Then you can do `WHERE NAME IN ($names)`. But you also will need to escape any quotes in the names.

Comment: If you can't get that to work, then .... where is the db access here? You can do `for (....) ; do printf "delete from TABLE1 where NAME in (${array[i]})]\n" ; done | isql -U... -S...` or similar. probably just `where name = '${arrayii]}\n"`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The content in array is string. And, for example, it has 100 elements in array. What I want to is to delete 10 elements at same time and repeat it 10 times (not 100 elements at same time).

Comment: Why do you want 5 or 10 rows at a time? Is it because you are wrapping the code in something making a connection to the database, run sql and disconnect?
Change that part that it can run a sql file with 10 commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an alternative way to do it (I don't have ksh, but it should be easy to adjust)

```
#/bin/bash

rc=0
while [ $rc -eq 0 ]; do
    rc=$(db2 "delete from (select * from table1 where name in ... fetch first 10 rows only) dt")
done
```

As long as the derived table dt uniquely identifies a row in table1 you can delete from it.

Another way is to stuff your parameters in a declared globally temporary table and use that in your delete. Can be handy if you have multiple predicates